# What does my slot class miss that std::function has?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, std-function

I wrote my own "slot" aka "callable wrapper" because I wanted to provide member function slot rebinding on other objects (i.e. I needed a way to store the member function pointer and a pointer to the class in question).

I ran a small size test and discovered `std::function` on my system (64-bit Linux) was twice (GCC/libstdc++) to three times (Clang/libc++) the size of my own implementation of a similar class, with a size of 16 bytes. The implementation for non-member functions and lambda's goes like this (the `const void*` first argument is for uniformity with member function slots not shown here):

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
class slot
{
public:
  virtual ~slot() = default;

  virtual void operator()(const void* object, ArgTypes...) const = 0;

protected:
  slot() = default;
};

template<typename Callable, typename... ArgTypes>
class callable_slot : public slot<ArgTypes...>
{
public:
  callable_slot(Callable function_pointer_or_lambda) : callable(function_pointer_or_lambda) {}

  virtual void operator()(const void*, ArgTypes... args) const override { callable(args...); }

private:
  Callable callable;
};

template<typename Callable>
class callable_slot<Callable> : public slot<>
{
public:
  callable_slot(Callable function_pointer_or_lambda) : callable(function_pointer_or_lambda) {}

  virtual void operator()(const void*) const override { callable(); }

private:
  Callable callable;
};

template<typename Callable, typename... ArgTypes>
using function_slot = callable_slot<Callable, ArgTypes...>;
```

I understand things like `target` aren't implemented here, but I don't think any of the missing functions increase the size of the object.

What I'm asking is: why is `std::function` larger in size than my cheap implementation above?

Comment: `std::function` has a small object optimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `function_slot` takes a `Callable` and set of `args...`, and returns a type inheriting from `slot<args...>` with a `virtual operator()`.

To use it polymorphically as a value, you'd have to wrap it in a smart pointer and store it on the heap, and you'd have to forward the wrapping classes `operator()` to the `slot<args...>` one.

`std::function` corresponds to *that wrapper*, not to your `slot` or `callable_slot` object.

```
template<class...Args>
struct smart_slot {
  template<class Callable> // add SFINAE tests here TODO! IMPORTANT!
  smart_slot( Callable other ):
    my_slot( std::make_unique<callable_slot<Callable, Args...>>( std::move(other) ) )
  {}
  void operator()( Args...args ) const {
    return (*my_slot)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  // etc
private:
  std::unique_ptr<slot<Args...>> my_slot;
};
```

`smart_slot` is closer to `std::function` than your code.  As far as `std::function` is concerned, everything you wrote is an implementation detail that users of `std::function` wouldn't ever see.

Now, this would only require that `std::function` be the size of one pointer.  `std::function` is larger because it has what is known as small object optimization.

Instead of just storing a smart pointer, it has a block of memory within itself.  If the object you pass in fits in that block of memory, it constructs it in-place that block of memory instead of doing a heap allocation.

`std::function` is basically mandated to do this for simple cases like being passed a function pointer.  Quality implementations do it for larger and more complex objects.  MSVC does it for objects up to the size of two `std::string`s.

This means if you do this:

```
std::function<void(std::ostream&)> hello_world =
  [s = "hello world"s](std::ostream& os)
  {
    os << s;
  };
hello_world(std::cout);
```

it does no dynamic allocation on a decent implementation of `std::function`.

Note that some major library vendors do dynamic allocation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your class functionality is very different from the one provided by `std::function`. You request users of your class to provide the actual type of 'callable' object as an argument of the template.

On the contrary, `std::function` does not require this, and can deal with **any** callable object, as long as it has `operator()` with required interface. Try using your template with an object of unknown type, for example, a result of `std::bind`, and you will know what I mean.

Since the functionality is very different, comparison of sizes is moot.

Comment: The type erasure can be handled by a make_slot helper function, no?